# OpenShift NodeJS Application 503 Error (port issue?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I am trying to create a NodeJS app for a school project. The basic idea is a NodeJS server which will process requests to it and track requests with a particular format (these will come from QR codes posted in various areas).

I want to use OpenShift to host the application, and I got it to build okay, but every time I got the URL posted it gives me a 503 error, even when I use a correctly formatted request (example: psychexpserver-psychexp.rhcloud.com/MU-EllisLib-Blue-NoPhrase). I've tested the app locally, and it works fine. I've researched the topic, but I found no answers that worked for my  Are the ports misconfigured? Should I be going to a different URL?

Code:

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var fs = require('fs');

    // Port which we listen to - get from OpenShift
    var serverPort = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 80;
    var serverIp = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

    app.set('port', serverPort);
    app.set('ipaddr', serverIp);

    // Data logging
    app.get('/:val', function(req, res)
                     {
                         // Grab request url
                         var data = req.url;
                         // Process and write to file
                         processData(data);
                         // Redirect to follow up form
                         res.redirect('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/11JbF4FE_Vd1Dd6PD8wMbs4Kxc15GgA3NL6vDGYEjtZY/viewform?c=0&w=1');
                     });

    function processData(data)
    {
        // Get timestamp
        var now = new Date();
        // Set time zone
        now.setHours(now.getHours() - 6);
        var timestamp = now.toUTCString();
        // Parse request
        var info = timestamp + ";_";

        // Sample communities and areas
        if(data.includes("RB"))
        {
             info += 'RB;_';
             // Sample area
             if(data.includes("North"))
                  info += 'North Coms;_';
             else if(data.includes("Main"))
                  info += 'Main Coms;_';            
             else if(data.includes("Atrium"))
                  info += 'Atrium;_';
        }
        else if(data.includes("MU"))
        {
             info += 'MU;_';
             // Sample area
             if(data.includes("Strickland"))
                  info += 'Strick;_';
             else if(data.includes("EllisLib"))
                  info += 'EllisLib;_';
             else if(data.includes("Engineering"))
                  info += 'Engineer;_';
        }
        else if(data.includes("DT"))
        {
             info += 'DT;_';
             // Sample area
             if(data.includes("North"))
                  info += 'North;_';
             else if(data.includes("West"))
                  info += 'West;_';
             else if(data.includes("East"))
                  info += 'East;_';
             else if(data.includes("South"))
                  info += 'South;_';
         }
         // Oh no, something's wrong
         else
         {
              info += 'Invalid Access;_';
         }

         // Color
         if(data.includes("Red"))
              info += 'Red;_';
         else if(data.includes("Blue"))
              info += 'Blue;_';
         else if(data.includes("Yellow"))
              info += 'Yellow;_';
         else if(data.includes("Blank"))
              info += 'Blank;_';

         // Phrase?
         if(data.includes("Phrase"))
              info += 'Phrase;';
         else if(data.includes("NoPhrase"))
              info += 'NoPhrase;';

         // Terminate line
         info += '__\t';
         // Log
         console.log('Got: ' + info);
         // Log into file
         fs.appendFileSync("data.txt", info, 'utf8');
     }

     http.listen(serverPort, serverIp, 
                   function()
                   {
                        console.log("Listening on: " + serverIp + ":" + serverPort);
                   });
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Hey guys, thanks all for your answers and suggestions. Unfortunately, the problem persists (at least for me) and, due to time constraints, I had to find a different hosting service. I will still check on this question to see if we can figure this problem out, though! Thanks again!

Comment: Did you try sshing into your app (`rhc ssh psychexpserver`) and checking the `~/app-root/logs/nodejs.log`?

Comment: Yes, the latest log messages show no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use `express` and `http` server and it's a bit mixed. Also, you expect the String object to have an `includes` function and store your `data.txt` so it won't survive git push on OpenShift Online. I have made a few small edits to your `server.js` code:

1. Use express:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   var fs = require('fs');
   ```
2. Prototype the `includes` method:

   ```
   String.prototype.includes = function(substr) {
     return this.indexOf(substr) != -1;
   }
   ```
3. Listen with the express:

   ```
   app.listen(serverPort, serverIp,
   ```
4. You would also want to place `data.txt` in the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` most likely, in order not to have it wiped with every git push, but I did not make any change here. See more details re the [persistent data storage](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html#__code_data_code) on OpenShift.

So now I have the below, which seems to be working on OpenShift's nodejs cartridge (I mean it logs things, does the redirect and stores `data.txt` in `~/app-root/runtime/repo/`):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

// Port which we listen to - get from OpenShift
var serverPort = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 80;
var serverIp = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

// Data logging
app.get('/:val', function(req, res)
                 {
                     // Grab request url
                     var data = req.url;
                     // Process and write to file
                     processData(data);
                     // Redirect to follow up form
                     res.redirect('http://goo.gl/forms/VGU9K99735');
                 });

function processData(data)
{
    // Get timestamp
    var now = new Date();
    // Set time zone
    now.setHours(now.getHours() - 6);
    var timestamp = now.toUTCString();
    // Parse request
    var info = timestamp + ";_";

    // seems like you want "includes" method for string objects
    String.prototype.includes = function(substr)
    {
      return this.indexOf(substr) != -1;
    }

    // Sample communities and areas
    if(data.includes("RB"))
    {
         info += 'RB;_';
         // Sample area
         if(data.includes("North"))
              info += 'North Coms;_';
         else if(data.includes("Main"))
              info += 'Main Coms;_';            
         else if(data.includes("Atrium"))
              info += 'Atrium;_';
    }
    else if(data.includes("MU"))
    {
         info += 'MU;_';
         // Sample area
         if(data.includes("Strickland"))
              info += 'Strick;_';
         else if(data.includes("EllisLib"))
              info += 'EllisLib;_';
         else if(data.includes("Engineering"))
              info += 'Engineer;_';
    }
    else if(data.includes("DT"))
    {
         info += 'DT;_';
         // Sample area
         if(data.includes("North"))
              info += 'North;_';
         else if(data.includes("West"))
              info += 'West;_';
         else if(data.includes("East"))
              info += 'East;_';
         else if(data.includes("South"))
              info += 'South;_';
     }
     // Oh no, something's wrong
     else
     {
          info += 'Invalid Access;_';
     }

     // Color
     if(data.includes("Red"))
          info += 'Red;_';
     else if(data.includes("Blue"))
          info += 'Blue;_';
     else if(data.includes("Yellow"))
          info += 'Yellow;_';
     else if(data.includes("Blank"))
          info += 'Blank;_';

     // Phrase?
     if(data.includes("Phrase"))
          info += 'Phrase;';
     else if(data.includes("NoPhrase"))
          info += 'NoPhrase;';

     // Terminate line
     info += '__\t';
     // Log
     console.log('Got: ' + info);
     // Log into file
     fs.appendFileSync("data.txt", info, 'utf8');
 }

app.listen(serverPort, serverIp, 
    function()
    {
        console.log("Listening on: " + serverIp + ":" + serverPort);
    });

//EOF
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response! I implemented the changes you suggested, but I still get a 503 error, and there are still no errors in the log file. The app runs fine when I test it locally, but OpenShift seems to not like it. Should I be using their NodeJS cartridge or the other user-created cartridge?

Comment: I used the above `server.js` code with the [Node.js 0.10 cartrdige](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_type/cart!nodejs-0.10), no dependencies added into `package.json`.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I tried your changes again, only now I cleaned up my package.json, which appears to have been messing with my app. It runs perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: np, I'm glad I could help